# Can I add custom #pragma rule?

Tags: c++

On ODB (C++ persistence library), `#pragma db` is using for reflection and so on, but it isn't standard or compiler-specific directive.

```
#pragma db object
class person
{
    ...
private:
    friend class odb::access;
    person () {}

    #pragma db id
    string email_;

    string name_;
    unsigned short age_;
};
```

Can I add custom #pragma rule on compiler like ODB?

Comment: You can't add custom #pragma support for your code. It is processed by preprocessor.

Comment: When you have the source of the compiler then you can add anything you want.  Calling it a compiler is a bit hohum, it is a preprocessor.

Comment: Okay... then, How can ODB use `#pragma db`? In general, Define a new preprocessor directive can't available in user-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is NOT a standard `#pragma`, it is actually consumed by the preprocessor for ODB, which spits out processed C++-code for the "real compiler".

You could do something similar, by writing a program that parses the source code and modifies it. It's not something you'd hack up in five minutes, but with some libraries (such as the libclang), you could feasibly read, process and output modified source-code, and send that to the compiler proper.

To produce real `#pragma` for the compiler itself, you would have to modify the source code of the compiler.

Edit: a relatively light-weight way to produce your own full compiler that supports custom pragmas would be to start with clang, and either build your own compiler-driver, or modify the cc1_main.cpp.

Then use the `Preprocessor::addPragmaHandler()` to introduce your own pragmas. This would be modifying the compiler, but really without having to change the actual compiler source code - maintaining a change to the actual compiler is much harder than having a "plugin" that you apply to the public interfaces of the compiler source code. Even if these do change, it's not at all as "busy" as the list of pragmas in the compiler source itself.

Comment: Finally, I should choose hack the compiler or write fake compiler(spits out C++ code for real compiler). isn't it?

Comment: Yes, one of those two. Which is better really depends on what you are trying to achieve, and whether that is possible within a preprocessing stage, or you actually need to tie the pragma to the code at a later stage. Obviously, without understanding what you are trying to actually achieve, it's not possible to say which is better. I will have a look at how pragmas work in clang, and see if another idea that I have will work - but it's not something I have been working on, and and it may take a while to figure out.

Comment: @LeeGom: See edit. I think that would "work", assuming clang is a suitable tool for your project.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no:  you can't define or redefine `#pragma`s or their parameters.

However, if you are willing to modify the compiler and preprocessor's source code, you can add all kinds of features.  If you have the source code, this is a medium-complexity task.

Note that many `#pragma`s correspond to a command line compiler option:  If one exists that is much easier to realize.